# Why is my XSLT template not displaying a table?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm fairly new to the whole XML and XSLT stuff. But I'm having an issue here. I need to print a table with all the information from the XML. "catalog" must be grouped and sorted by author. But to start it should be like this-

> Author: Gambardella,
>   Matthew Author: Ralls, Kim

etc...

with each Author in a table cell.
But its only displaying
Author:

with nothing else

What might I be doing wrong here? Some guidance is appreciated.

My XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="catalog.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<catalog>
<book id="bk101">
  <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
  <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
  <genre>Computer</genre>
  <price>44.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
  <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
  with XML.</description>
 </book>
 <book id="bk102">
  <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
  <title>Midnight Rain</title>
  <genre>Fantasy</genre>
  <price>5.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
  <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
  an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
  of the world.</description>
 </book>
 <book id="bk103">
  <author>Corets, Eva</author>
  <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
  <genre>Fantasy</genre>
  <price>5.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>
  <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology 
  society in England, the young survivors lay the 
  foundation for a new society.</description>
 </book>
 <book id="bk104">
  <author>Corets, Eva</author>
  <title>Oberon's Legacy</title>
  <genre>Fantasy</genre>
  <price>5.95</price>
  <publish_date>2001-03-10</publish_date>
  <description>In post-apocalypse England, the mysterious 
  agent known only as Oberon helps to create a new life 
  for the inhabitants of London. Sequel to Maeve 
  Ascendant.</description>
 </book>
 <book id="bk105">
  <author>Corets, Eva</author>
  <title>The Sundered Grail</title>
  <genre>Fantasy</genre>
  <price>5.95</price>
  <publish_date>2001-09-10</publish_date>
  <description>The two daughters of Maeve, half-sisters, 
  battle one another for control of England. Sequel to 
  Oberon's Legacy.</description>
 </book>
 <book id="bk106">
  <author>Randall, Cynthia</author>
  <title>Lover Birds</title>
  <genre>Romance</genre>
  <price>4.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-09-02</publish_date>
  <description>When Carla meets Paul at an ornithology 
  conference, tempers fly as feathers get ruffled.</description>
 </book>
 <book id="bk107">
  <author>Thurman, Paula</author>
  <title>Splish Splash</title>
  <genre>Romance</genre>
  <price>4.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-11-02</publish_date>
  <description>A deep sea diver finds true love twenty 
  thousand leagues beneath the sea.</description>
 </book>
 <book id="bk108">
  <author>Knorr, Stefan</author>
  <title>Creepy Crawlies</title>
  <genre>Horror</genre>
  <price>4.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-12-06</publish_date>
  <description>An anthology of horror stories about roaches,
  centipedes, scorpions  and other insects.</description>
 </book>
 <book id="bk109">
  <author>Kress, Peter</author>
  <title>Paradox Lost</title>
  <genre>Science Fiction</genre>
  <price>6.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-11-02</publish_date>
  <description>After an inadvertant trip through a Heisenberg
  Uncertainty Device, James Salway discovers the problems 
  of being quantum.</description>
 </book>
 <book id="bk110">
  <author>O'Brien, Tim</author>
  <title>Microsoft .NET: The Programming Bible</title>
  <genre>Computer</genre>
  <price>36.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-12-09</publish_date>
  <description>Microsoft's .NET initiative is explored in 
  detail in this deep programmer's reference.</description>
 </book>
 <book id="bk111">
  <author>O'Brien, Tim</author>
  <title>MSXML3: A Comprehensive Guide</title>
  <genre>Computer</genre>
  <price>36.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-12-01</publish_date>
  <description>The Microsoft MSXML3 parser is covered in 
  detail, with attention to XML DOM interfaces, XSLT processing, 
  SAX and more.</description>
 </book>
 <book id="bk212">
  <author>Galos, Mike</author>
  <title>Visual Studio 7: A Comprehensive Guide</title>
  <genre>Computer</genre>
  <price>49.95</price>
  <publish_date>2001-04-16</publish_date>
  <description>Microsoft Visual Studio 7 is explored in depth,
  looking at how Visual Basic, Visual C++, C#, and ASP+ are 
  integrated into a comprehensive development 
  environment.</description>
 </book>
</catalog>
```

XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:template match="catalog">        
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Books Catalog by Author</title>
            </head>            
            <body>
                <h1>Books Catalog by Author</h1>                
                <table BORDER="1" CELLPADDING="5">
                    <xsl:for-each-group select="book" group-by="author">
                        <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                        <tr bgcolor="#ef9f37">
                            <td colspan="6">Author:
                                <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>                      
                    </xsl:for-each-group>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: How are you performing the transformation? The use of the `xml-stylesheet` directive in your XML suggests you doing so directly in the browser, in which case only XSLT 1.0 would be supported.

Comment: *Im fairly new to the whole XML and XLST stuff*. You don't need to tell us that. Just misspell it XLST, and we already know.

Comment: @TimC im doing it in eclipse

Comment: Can you be sure Eclipse is using an XSLT 2.0 processor? Try adding the line `<xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:version')" />` to your stylesheet to find out.